# How do you read JSON files in apache beam (dataflow) via python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to read a JSON file via apache beam in python and apply some data quality rules over it. 
Currently I'm using beam.io.ReadFromText to read each json line and use some functions to modify the data. 
What would be a better way to read the JSON data and modify them ?

```
(p
  | 'Getdata' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input)
  | 'filter_name' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda line: dq_name(line))
  | 'filter_phone' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda line: dq_phone(line))
  | 'filter_zip' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda line: dq_zip(line))
  | 'filter_address' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda line: dq_city(line))
  | 'filter_website' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda line: dq_website(line))
  | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToText(output_prefix)  )
```

Note: I'm fairly new to this, I'm sorry if my current approach looks too shoddy of stupid.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Is anything in particular wrong with your current approach?

Comment: I did not know that I had to convert the json into ndjson, so when each line was being read I was not able to understand how to read entire json file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are approaching Apache Beam (Dataflow) from the wrong direction.

You are trying to read a line and then apply transforms to this line one at a time.

Instead, you need to look at Beam being a parallel processor. You will read in all the lines `ReadFromText()` and then apply transforms to each line in parallel.

Look into the function `beam.ParDo()`. This will allow you to create a class that can process each line of your JSON file. Your code would then have major steps like `ReadFromText()`, `ParDo(MyJsonProcessor())`, `WriteToText()`.

Remember that your JSON will need to be Newline Delimited JSON. http://ndjson.org/

Comment: Thank you! using ndjson solves it. Sorry for the ignorance. One more thing, How does one go about performing deduplication ? could you just point me to what I should research about?

Comment: A Google search should result in a lot of hits. Deduplication for large (100 GB+) datasets is hard because of space and time required. It just depends on what the data is, and how it is being generated and consumed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your pipeline is okay. It will run in parallel without any problem. FYI, if you use `FlatMap` just for filtering elements, you can also use [`Filter`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.12.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Filter.html).